# Using module params in javascript (javascript in php)

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have a simple module, and now I want to use custom module parameters in my javascript file. If I use js extension, I can not use php code, but if I try this:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addScript(JURI::root() . 'modules/mod_homenewslist/js/newslist.php');
```

I get following error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Inside newslist.php I tried following:

```
<?php echo' <script type="text/javascript">' ?>
console.log(300);
<?php echo "</script>"; ?>
```

and:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log(300);
</script>;
```

The result is the same. Is it possible to load php as script, or to use module parameters in js file?

Comment: </script>; semicolumn is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of the code in your **newlist.js** file, you could always do it all via PHP like so:

```
<?php
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $doc->addScriptDeclaration('
       alert(' . $params->get('param_name') . ');
       //more js code here
    '); 
?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This helps, but JS code will get a bit large (at the moment it is around 200 lines, but I am just starting :D). I got an idea - I can declare JS vairable inside this line of code and then use it inside JS. Mate you helped me a lot in last few day :). Thank you a lot :). If I may ask - are you a member of Joomla development team?

Comment: Glad it helped. You're right, declaring JS variables will be much better when the files starts getting bigger ;) No, I'm not a member of the Joomla development team, I only developer Joomla extensions :)